# Uninstall Canon MP280 drivers

Tags: windows-7, drivers, printer

I have Windows 7 home premium.

I am trying to uninstall canon MP280 series drivers from my machine. I am using "uninstall or change a program" in the programs and features section of the control panel. I follow the on screen prompts but get advised to "disconnect the printer cable from the computer and try again" but there is no printer cable attached to the machine. Looking in printers and devises the printer does not exist.

Any help gratefully received.

Clive

Comment: Go to start->Run-> in the box type "spool". It should open a new window. Next open the PRINTERS folders and if there are any files delete them.

Comment: Have you tried to delete you printer device from ``Devices and Printers``? ``Start->Devices and printers`` choose your device and click delete.

Comment: Thanks to both of you for your replies. User @552853, typing in spool gives the response "no items match your search. Alljamin, the only place I can see any ref to the MP280 is in the uninstall or change program section of the control panel

Answer (score 0):

If all else fails, try hacking the printer from the registry. Go to

HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE > SYSTEM > CurrentControlSet > Control > Print > Environments > Windows NT x86 > Drivers > Version-3

Right-click the printer in the left pane and delete it. If you have a 64-bit system, also delete it from

HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE > SYSTEM > CurrentControlSet > Control > Print > Environments > Windows x64 > Drivers > Version-3

Now stop and restart the spooler and reinstall the printer.

Comment: Thanks for this but being a bit thick I don't know how to access the registry. Can you enlighten me please? Thanks

Comment: Press Win+R and type REGEDIT. After it starts, you may want to back up the registry first. Click on Computer (at the top of the left pane). Then go to File > Export. Give the backup a name and save. Then follow my suggestion.

Comment: Thanks again for your help but there is no printer in either of the locations that you have suggested. Easy to follow instruction though, much appreciated. Clive

Comment: Just in case it is a network printer (attached to another PC), you need to remove it from HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Printers\Connections\ and HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\Print\Providers\ LanMan Print Services\Servers\\Printers\

Comment: Thanks hdhondt, still nothing in either of those locations. Clive